# how to store and retrieve perl objects

Tags: perl

Problem : I want to have a list of objects stored so that i can call the corresponding methods at latter point in time

```
my @tc = ("TC_1","TC_2");
my %obj_list = ();
foreach my $test (@tc) {
     $obj_list{$test} = Test->new($test);
 }
```

In the same module file at latter stage where i need to call the corresponding methods of those objects

```
foreach my $test (keys %obj_list) {
         if (some specific condition is satisfied for a test) {
         1 --> $obj_list->$test->action();
         2 --> $obj_list{$test}->action(); 
      }
 }
```

I tried 1 and 2 and they are not working. Could some one tell me what i could be doing wrong here.Any inputs would be of great help.

Comment: Is this your real code? It has very basic errors.  In principle, you can indeed just put objects in an array or a hash; they are references.  Then you can use them as you attempted.  Please clarify whether this is your code and if not show us the real code.

Comment: `@tc = ("TC_1","TC_2")` to create an array or `$tc = ["TC_1","TC_2"]` to create an array reference.

Comment: `foreach (keys %obj_list)` and then you use (non-existent) `$key`

Comment: sorry i was typing pseudo code here and i made the mistakes. i will correct the same and give the exact code here

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code is *basically* correct - other than a few syntax errors.

```
# Use ( ... ) to initialise an array.
my @tc = ("TC_1","TC_2");
my %obj_list = ();
foreach my $test (@tc) {
  $obj_list{$test} = Test->new($test);
}

foreach (keys %obj_list) {
  if (some specific condition is satisfied for a test) {
    # This version is incorrect
    # $obj_list->$key->action();

    # This version will work, except you have the
    # key in $_, not $key.
    $obj_list{$_}->action(); 
  }
}
```

Adding `use strict` and `use warnings` to your code would have helped you find some of these problems.